# Extending Controller - Nothing Happens

Tags: symfony, controller, bundle

I'm trying to figure that problem for a long day.

I have Sonata User Bundle installed and I use it to manage users and profile edition and so on.

BUT, I a need to override Sonata Profile Controller.

If I understood correctly (I'm a perfect beginner in Symfony), I have to extend SonataUserBundle (which has been done using the easy extend bundle).

So, when I declare a new controller, nothing happens. Not even an error message.

Any ideas ?

Here are my files

[ BUNDLE EXTENSION FILE ]

```
   // ApplicationSonataUserBundle.php

    namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle;

    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

    class ApplicationSonataUserBundle extends Bundle
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getParent()
        {
            return 'SonataUserBundle';
        }
    }
```

[ CONTROLLER FILE ]

```
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Controller;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileFOSUser1Controller as BaseController;

class ProfileFOSUser1Controller extends BaseController {

    public function editProfileAction() {
    die('toto');
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    $form = $this->get('sonata.user.profile.form');
    $formHandler = $this->get('sonata.user.profile.form.handler');

    $process = $formHandler->process($user);
    if ($process) {
        $this->setFlash('sonata_user_success', 'profile.flash.updated');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('sonata_user_profile_edit'));
    }

    return $this->render('SonataUserBundle:Profile:edit_profile.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'breadcrumb_context' => 'user_profile',
    ));
    }

}
```

Comment: What does "nothing happens" mean exactly?

Comment: It means that when I call the route calling for Sonata Profile edit, it should call this controller instead of the legacy Sonata Controller. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I have found the answer by myself :)

I forgot to specify the classes I needed

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileFOSUser1Controller as BaseController;
```

I cleared the cache and everything was ok !

Thanks all !

Answer (score 1):

You have `die('toto');` as first line in the controller method, isn't that going to terminate all code below?

Comment: I use the die() to see if the Controller is detected. No error, nothing.